# ArcMap Mosaic Dataset function chain result to NetCDF

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, 3d-analyst, netcdf, arcscene

I've been working on a mosaic dataset and added some changes by using the function chain options. This works fine in ArcMap and I can create a time varying result out of this. Since I want a 3D result as well using ArcScene and ArcScene can't handle mosaic datasets, I tried to convert the Mosaic Dataset to NetCDF. Unfortunately it seems that ArcMap doesn't convert the final result from the function chain. How can I get this to work, so I can get my function chain result visualized in ArcScene?